android studio getting Caused by: org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMException: malformed sequence in RSA private key when trying to run test
i'm trying to run basic test does not include any encryption but im getting  this error:
caused by: org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMException: malformed sequence in RSA private key

logs:
2024-12-07T23:12:32.487+0100 [DEBUG] [org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.statistics.KotlinBuildStatHandler] Executing [report metric STATISTICS_COLLECT_METRICS_OVERHEAD]
2024-12-07T23:12:32.487+0100 [DEBUG] [org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.statistics.KotlinBuildStatHandler] Executing [class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.statistics.KotlinBuildStatHandler.reportGlobalMetrics]
2024-12-07T23:12:32.487+0100 [DEBUG] [org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.statistics.KotlinBuildStatHandler] Executing [class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.statistics.KotlinBuildStatHandler.reportBuildFinish]
2024-12-07T23:12:32.488+0100 [DEBUG] [org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.statistics.KotlinBuildStatHandler] Executing [report metric STATISTICS_COLLECT_METRICS_OVERHEAD]
2024-12-07T23:12:32.488+0100 [DEBUG] [org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.statistics.KotlinBuildStatHandler] Executing [class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.statistics.KotlinBuildStatHandler.buildFinished]
2024-12-07T23:12:32.490+0100 [DEBUG] [org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.statistics.KotlinBuildStatHandler] Executing [report metric STATISTICS_COLLECT_METRICS_OVERHEAD]
2024-12-07T23:12:32.512+0100 [DEBUG] [org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinGradleFinishBuildHandler] [KOTLIN] Deleted session-is-alive flag file: kotlin\sessions\kotlin-compiler-16261734698672361384.salive
2024-12-07T23:12:32.512+0100 [DEBUG] [org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinGradleBuildServices$Inject] [KOTLIN] Disposed KotlinGradleBuildServices
2024-12-07T23:12:32.513+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Finish root build tree'
2024-12-07T23:12:32.513+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Finish root build tree' completed
2024-12-07T23:12:32.515+0100 [WARN] [org.gradle.internal.featurelifecycle.LoggingDeprecatedFeatureHandler] 
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
2024-12-07T23:12:32.515+0100 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 

i'm not using any rsa , how do i fix this?

Posting a stack-trace doesn't suffice for a proper question, because it is entirely unclear which code caused it and how that key had been created. I could close this as duplicate, but I won't since this might stem from tooling, which is a minor difference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39412297

This may well be caused by a KGP version conflict, while the Gradle and Kotlin version are unknown. If not, this may be worth filing a bug on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com ... https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-plugin-variants.html#troubleshooting
